# If selected cell is colored

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to do, that if you select a cell, and it is colored red, a `MsgBox` would pop out?

I tried something like this:

```
Sub isitred()
    If ActiveCell = "vbRed" Then
        MsgBox "ActiveCell is Red"

    End If
End Sub
```

But it doesnt work... Any ideas?

Comment: If activecell = vbred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
If ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
  MsgBox ...
End If
```

If vbRed is not defined, you can use the value of 255.

Comment: It works, how to launch this code without a button? I mean, that the msgbox would appear after you click red cell?

Comment: The question is, what do you want overall behavior to be? I'd read up on Excel macros in general.macros can be kicked off when a spreadsheet opens, when a certain hotkey combination is pressed, or froma  button. It all dependson your requirements

Comment: @Faux https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Run-a-macro-5e855fd2-02d1-45f5-90a3-50e645fe3155

Comment: I want something like, when you walk with arrow keys through cells, and you step on red cell, a message would pop up, how could i do that?

Comment: @Faux, Take a look at the Worksheet_Change event.

Comment: read the articles I posted. If still confused, ask another question with the specific code you tried...and upvote my answer because it answered your question :)

Comment: Thank you, i figured it out :)

Comment: How to add another color? If red then msg box its red, and if green msgbox its green, can you update your code?

Comment: @Faux Right click on vbRed and choose "Go to Definition" This shows all of the other colors available via constants.

Comment: Thats not what i meant. Why do i get an error (block if without end if) when i add `If ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
  MsgBox "Red"
  If ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen Then
  MsgBox "Green"`

Comment: please do some basic research. http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php